# Is it possible to import/require js function via webpack?

Tags: typescript, webpack, import, require

I have a vanilla JS library. Let's say:

*call-my-name.js*

```
function CallMyName (name) { alert(name); }
```

And I want to use this method in other (.ts) file;

*big-class.ts*

```
import CallMyName from './call-my-name.js'

export class BigClass {

    constructor () {
        CallMyName ('test');
    }
}
```

I've tried:

```
import CallMyName from 'script-loader!./call-my-name.js'
import CallMyName from 'babel-loader!./call-my-name.js'
```

*but it's not module, so got error*

```
require('./call-my-name.js')
```

*returns {}*

The main thing - I can't change JS file. It's 3rd party library.

(but just adding *export default CallMyName* solves the problem)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is import it like this:

```
import './call-my-name.js’
```

And the function inside it should be globally available.

Comment: I'd prefere to use it locally. Don't want to share it globally

Comment: @Kindzoku no other way to do that without adding export default, as you mentioned already